# How to control form validity from other directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My form is:

```
<form name="regForm" novalidate>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback" form-validation>
            <label class="control-label">Username</label>
            <div ensure-unique="{{user.username}}">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"
                       ng-model="user.username"
                       required
                       ng-minlength="3" />
            </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

In **ensure-unique** directive I'm checking if the username taken or not, and in that case if username used I want to set my *username* field to **invalid**.
How can I do that, if I don't want to apply **ensure-unique** directive to `<input>` element? Because I want to isolate scope of this directive and use `ng-transclude`. When I'm applying on input element the `ng-transclude` doesn't work.

Comment: Is the `checking if the username is already taken` process an ajax request? I mean it can be done synchronously or not?

Comment: So whenever the input value is changed you want to set it as invalid first, then request an ajax request to see if the value is valid, if yes set the input into valid state?

Comment: exactly , but I dont know how to  access form, because I cant require ngModel in my `ensure-unique` directive

Comment: You can require `'^form'` and get the corresponding `ngModel` by input's name. Something like `formCtrl['username']`.

Comment: thanks I think it will work, but I've decided to do in another way :)

Comment: Would you mind telling me which way you are trying? However, you can have a look here: http://jsbin.com/cequp/18/edit for an example of the `require: '^form'`

Comment: yes you answer is satisfies me, can you write it as answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could require a parent form controller, then get the corresponding ngModel controller by input's name like `formCtrl['username']`:

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    isPending: '=',
  },
  require: '^form',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
    var modelCtrl = formCtrl[attrs.ensureUnique];

    if (!modelCtrl) { return; }

    var counter = 0;
    scope.isPending = false;

    var validator = function (value) {
      modelCtrl.$setValidity('unique', false);
      scope.isPending = true;

      var currentCount = ++counter;

      checkUnique(value).then(function (isUnique) {
        if (currentCount !== counter) { return; }

        modelCtrl.$setValidity('unique', isUnique);
        scope.isPending = false;
      });

      return value;
    };

    modelCtrl.$parsers.push(validator);
    modelCtrl.$formatters.push(validator);
  }
};
```

**Example:** http://jsbin.com/cequp/18/edit

Answer (score 0):

I would have the ensure-unique directive modify its transcluded contents within its compile function by adding another directive to the input element. Something like 'nameToCheck' directive, which is set to `user.username`.

The nameToCheck directive would 'require' ng-model and import ng-model's controller inside its link function. Within the link function, check if the username is unique: if it is not unique, then set the validity flag:

```
scope: true,
require: 'ngModel',
link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelController) {
      var username = scope.$eval(attr.nameToCheck);
      if (// username taken //) {
          ngModelController.$setValidity('unique', false);
      }
      else { 
          ngModelController.$setValidity('unique', true);
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think its a bit messed ? or may be I understood wrongly, can bring example if it possible ?

Comment: Sure, but you first;)

Comment: are you able to use transclusion on <input> element ?

Comment: No, transclusion is on the parent div - like you have in your example.

Comment: actually my question was about that are we able to use ng-transclude on input elements or not

Comment: Ah, I see. No, you can't have transclusion on an input element. An input element cannot have any children.